# How to run interactive Centos 6 within docker

Tags: docker, centos, centos6

I'm unable to run an interactive session with Centos:6 in docker. Works perfectly with Centos:7

```
>docker -v
Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24302
>docker pull centos:6
...
>docker run -it centos:6
[just returns to my terminal]

>docker pull centos:7
...
>docker run -it centos:7
>[root@f8c0430ed2ba /]#cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
```

Any idea what is going on ?

I tried with older version of docker and i pulled all new images Centos:6/6.6/6.7/6.8/6.9 and it shows the same problems. I also tried with /bin/bash or sh at the end.

Also i'm sure that it used to work more or less one year ago.
I'm using ArchLinux

Comment: `docker run -it centos:6 sh` what if you add `sh` at the end?

Comment: same behavior (except for centos 6.6 that actually requires it)

Comment: did test it here. Worked like expected. Could you delete the image and pull it again?

Comment: That is exactly what I have done first. Wich version of docker are you using ?

Comment: `Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24` here, worked as expected...

Comment: I'm on ArchLinux, what about you ?

Comment: windows 7 and osx, both `18.02.0-ce, build fc4de447b5`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a known issue that seems to be linked to the Spectre patch:

[issue 103](https://github.com/CentOS/sig-cloud-instance-images/issues/103) says:

> Running a docker run --rm -it centos:6 bash fails with exit status 139 (i.e. bash exits with SIGSEGV) on Linux kernel 4.15.9. Downgrading to 4.14.15 (which is vulnerable to Spectre V1) gets rid of the segfault.

Comment: I confirm that downgrading my kernel resolve the issue. However i do not have the mentionned error on `4.15.12-1-ARCH` kernel